# Retrieving the correct http error for requests in js

Tags: javascript, http, https, certificate, fetch

I want to programmatically upgrade a website from http to https. For this purpose i check the domain that points to the website with a js script if it is already available. We want to also allow self signed certificates for testing environments.

Essentially i am requesting a website until it does not throw an error anymore and redirect afterwards, but this works only for correctly signed certificates. For self signed certificates the fetch/axios call throws an error like this: `"message":"Network Error"`. The error is super generic and is the same if the cert authority is unknown and if there is no connection via https available.

But i think that there must be a way to determine if there was an error with the cert authority, because the browser throws this error: `net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`.

Example application:

```js
try{
  axios.get('https://domain.with.selfsigned.certificate.com')
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error inside: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}catch(err){
   console.log("Error outside: "+JSON.stringify(err))
}
```

Anyone knows how to get the correct error or knows a workaround? If i get the correct error i can try to redirect or return the correct error to the user so he can decide, but right now i am stuck because the error is nonsense for me.

Comment: From your frontend JavaScript code, there is not a way to determine if there was an error with the cert authority. That information is intentionally not exposed to your frontend JavaScript code. The browser logs it to the devtools console, but there are many things that the browser logs in the devtools console that aren’t exposed to your frontend JavaScript code.

Comment: Okay.. what good reason would there be to not expose the correct error? 

Maybe i am doing something entirely wrong